# BrowserSync suddenly not connecting to browser

Tags: javascript, browser, synchronization, gulp, browser-sync

Last week I tried writing a gulpfile from scratch for a small javascript project. I chose to use BrowserSync to compile my code and reload the browser (Chrome). It was working well throughout the weekend and I got the done. However, I feel like I opened up the project yesterday and now when I run the 'gulp' command it doesn't connect to the browser, give the "Connected to BrowserSync" message, and provide the autoreload functionality. However in the console, I still get notified that my files are getting updated and compiled.

Does anyone have any idea how this could happen?

Here's the gulpfile I'm using:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
gutil = require('gulp-util'),
browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
reload = browserSync.reload,
jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
  var files = [
    'app/**/*/.html',
    'app/assets/css/**/*.css',
    'app/assets/js/**/*.js'
    ];

  browserSync.init(files, {
    server: {
      baseDir: './app'
    }
  });
});

// process JS files and reload all browsers when complete.
gulp.task('js', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/assets/js/*js')
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets/js'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}));
});

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/assets/sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets/css'))
    .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

// Reload all Browsers
gulp.task('bs-reload', function () {
    browserSync.reload();
});

gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync'], function() {
  gulp.watch('app/assets/js**/*.js', ['js']);
  gulp.watch('app/assets/sass/*.scss', ['sass']);
  gulp.watch('app/*html', ['bs-reload']);
});
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: It sounds like the script tag is not getting injected into your pages. Can you view source and check if the browser-sync script tag is there.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like the browsersync 'script' tag is not being injected in the html file you are serving from, re-check your html file , Sometimes i forget the body tag , If there is no body tag the script tag won't be injected.

when you run gulp , and your page loads up check out the source code (view page source) while it's opened up and check the html structure.

You can copy the tag from other project that you have working fine , run it and copy the script tag injected and paste it on your current project page.

the script tag looks like this (might be diffrent depending on BrowserSync version)

```
<body>
   <script id="__bs_script__">
     //<![CDATA[document.write("<script async src='/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.js?v=2.18.5'><\/script>".replace("HOST", location.hostname));//]]>
   </script>
```

> Notice: In the above `<script>` tag `browser-sync` version is `2.18.5` make sure to replace that with your installed version of browser-sync

Comment: It always pays to use good programming practices. I got away with putting tags in chrome without any HTML structure. Thanks!

Comment: Strangely my code passed HTML validator but the script was still not included, adding it back by hand solved it!

Comment: It turns out that the **body tag is mandatory**! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and it turned out that commenting out body tag before actual body tag causes browsersync to stop injecting the script tag and hence refreshing the page. See examples:

THIS DOES NOT WORK:

```
<!-- <body> -->
<body class="modal_on">
```

THIS WORKS:

```
<body class="modal_on">
<!-- <body> -->
```

*I'm using browsersync version 2.26.14*